# android progressbar inside edittext

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-edittext

I want to display progressbar(spinner) to the right of editText when activity is doing some processing and hide upon completion, is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I'd use `RelativeLayout`, something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/the_id"/>
    <ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/the_id"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/the_id"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/the_id"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this...

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

             <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/app_name"
                android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
                android:padding="8dp" >
             </EditText>

             <ProgressBar
                  style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleInverse"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_alignBottom="@id/editText"
                  android:layout_alignRight="@id/editText"
                  android:layout_alignTop="@id/editText" />
             </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

Late answer, but, maybe someone will use this.

I created a new view that is actually doing the job for me.

So, first of all, create layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

<com.view.InstantAutoComplete
    android:id="@+id/custom_edit_text_edit_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="@dimen/layout_padding"/>

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/custom_edit_text_progress_bar"
    style="@style/SmallProgressBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:visibility="gone"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now, a java class:

```
public class CustomEditText extends RelativeLayout {

    private LayoutInflater mInflater = null;
    private AutocompleteEditText mEditText;
    private ProgressBar mProgressBar;
    private boolean mIsRefreshing = false;


    private int textColor;

    private int hintTextColor;
    private String hint;

    private int textSize;

    public CustomEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initViews(attrs);
    }

    public CustomEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        initViews(attrs);
    }

    private void initViews(AttributeSet attrs) {
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout_edit_text, this, true);
        mEditText = (AutocompleteEditText) findViewById(R.id.custom_edit_text_edit_text);
        mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.custom_edit_text_progress_bar);

        mProgressBar.getLayoutParams().height = mEditText.getLayoutParams().height - 30;
        mProgressBar.getLayoutParams().width = mEditText.getLayoutParams().height - 30;
        mProgressBar.requestLayout();


        TypedArray a = getContext().getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CustomEditText, 0, 0);
        try {
            textColor = a.getInteger(R.styleable.CustomEditText_textColor, R.color.black);
            hint = a.getString(R.styleable.CustomEditText_hint);
            hintTextColor = a.getInteger(R.styleable.CustomEditText_hintTextColor, R.color.black);
            textSize = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.CustomEditText_textSize, R.dimen.text_medium_size);
        } finally {
            a.recycle();
        }

        mEditText.setTextColor(textColor);
        mEditText.setHint(hint);
        mEditText.setHintTextColor(hintTextColor);
        mEditText.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, textSize);
    }

    public void setRefreshing(boolean isVisible) {
        if (isVisible) {
            if (!mIsRefreshing) {
                mIsRefreshing = true;
                mProgressBar.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            }
        } else {
            if (mIsRefreshing) {
                mIsRefreshing = false;
                mProgressBar.setVisibility(GONE);
            }
        }


    }

    public AutocompleteEditText getEditText() {
        return mEditText;
    }

    public ProgressBar getProgressBar() {
        return mProgressBar;
    }
}
```

Define your attributes so you can use it in xml. In your values folder, create a .xml file named attrs:

```
<resources>

    <declare-styleable name="CustomEditText">
        <attr name="hint" format="string"/>
        <attr name="textColor" format="color"/>
        <attr name="textSize" format="dimension"/>
        <attr name="hintTextColor" format="color"/>
    </declare-styleable>

</resources>
```

And finally use it in you activity/fragment like:

```
<com.CustomEditText
                    android:id="@+id/reply_to_request_main_course_edit_text"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/layout_padding"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    app:textColor="@color/black"
                    app:textSize="@dimen/text_medium_size"/>
```

You instansiate object in activity/fragment. When you want to call the progress bar to be visible, just type

```
mEditText.setRefreshing(true/false);
```

Comment: Could you add the color.xml and dimen.xml values that you used?

Answer (score 2):

Use FrameLayout to achieve this in the best way. FrameLayout help us to add ProgressBar inside EditText. Check this :

```
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_mobile"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/pb_login"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end|center_vertical"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Result :

[image]