# How to put ProgressBar inside of EditText and keep the bar right in it?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to have a ProgressBar inside of an EditText, but I want it to be right inside it and, preferably, in the center of the EditText. All the solutions I've come across so far do not really allow the bar to be inside of the borders. Also, I'm looking for as clean solution as possible, not just putting over 9000 constraints in ConstraintLayout.

It should look like this (picture is taken from [android progressbar inside edittext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4493704/android-progressbar-inside-edittext/49626692#49626692)):

[image: Expected result]

But the actual result is either this:

[image: Actual result]

or this (if I use smaller style for the bar):

[image: Actual result]

My code is:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="10dp">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|center_vertical"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Of course, I could just put some hardcoded values for height, but it's definitely a bad fix of the problem. Also, if I change the style of the bar to the smaller one, it's not a fix, since I want to have some control over it (and it doesn't look perfect, either). I'm planning to add something like error and success icons also, so the solution that fulfills this requirement is extremely welcome! So, if you have any clue about how to put it properly inside of the input field, I'll be grateful.

Thanks in advance, guys!

Comment: change 'android:layout_gravity' property of ProgressBar to change its position over EditText. Also you might want to look at https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/textfield/TextInputLayout for showing error

Comment: Thanks! The link you gave me is pretty useful

Answer (score 0):

You can achive like this, Whenever you want to position children inside a layout `FrameLayout` is not a good layout to use. consider using `RelativeLayout` or better `ConstraintLayout`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@null"
        android:hint="Phone number goes here" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:padding="5dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Happy coding!!

[image]

Comment: Nice solution actually, but is it a clean approach to use these values that define the size of the ProgressBar? It seems for me it's better to avoid them

Comment: its a good idea to make progress bar have a fixed size in this case wrap_content has a very big size. and it don't fit

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_text"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

   <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: My EditText dissapears from the app with this. It shows fine in the design tab